# Unable to attach EFS to EC2s. We tried various ways to mount, even it is throwing the same error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-efs

Unable to attach EFS to EC2s. We tried various ways to mount, even it is throwing the same error .  logs:

mount -t nfs4 -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport fs-c04ksakbe520.efs.us-wsjn-1.amazonaws.com :/ efs mount.nfs4: Connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

we found that the VPC was using a custom DNS in the DHCP option set to resolve Company on premises URLs. In order to mount an EFS using the DNS name, the connecting EC2 instance must be inside a VPC and must be configured to use the DNS server provided by Amazon [1]. Using the IP address of the mount target in the same Availability Zone as the instance (us-east-1a), we were able to mount the EFS [2] using the following command:

mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport 83.23.23.4:/ efs-mount-point

Then added the following line to the /etc/fstab file in order to mount the EFS automatically on boot:

83.23.23.4:/    /mnt/efs     nfs4    nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport,_netdev    0    0

tested successfully by running "mount -a"

Mounting on Amazon EC2 with a DNS Name - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-mount-cmd-dns-name.html 
Mounting File Systems Without the EFS Mount Helper - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/mounting-fs-old.html